# Read Sentinel-2 zip-file into memory using gdal in python

Tags: python, gdal, remote-sensing, sentinel-2

I was wondering if there's a way to read a Sentinel-2 zipfile directly into memory through python without extracting the whole thing or selected contents.

I figured since GDAL does have a driver for the S2 format, it should be somehow possible to open the zipfile in python and then read the bands into arrays separately.

Another approach I was thinking about is the `zipfile` module in python. I came as far as accessing the single files in the archive, but I haven't managed yet to read them into memory or pass them over to GDAL.

Edit:

Sorry, I forgot to mention I'm generally looking for a platform-independent solution

Edit2:

Also, I intend to stay away from ESA's snappy

---

**Solution:**

Alright, after the helpful tips I got here I finally implemented the following solution. I ended up installing **gdal 2.1.3** from `conda-forge` inside a new environment to bypass any dependency issues. There's still an issue with the UTF encoding using `vsizip` which can be fixed setting the corresponding environment variable as discribed in  [this issue on github](https://github.com/conda-forge/gdal-feedstock/issues/83).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import gdal
from zipfile import ZipFile
import re
import os

## vsizip bugfix
os.environ['CPL_ZIP_ENCODING'] = 'UTF-8'

#choose tile 
tile = 'T36PXV'

tileREXP = re.compile(r'.*(%s).*B(02|03|04|05|06|07|08|8A|11|12).jp2$' %tile)

# sort bands 2 - 12 with 8A after 8
bndIX = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10,8]

with open('S2_FILELIST.txt') as flist:
    for filename in flist:
        with ZipFile(filename,'r') as zfile:
            bands = [x for x in zfile.namelist() if re.match(tileREXP,x)]
            bands.sort()
            bands =  [x for (y,x) in zip(bndIX,bands)]
            for b in bands:
                ds = gdal.Open('/vsizip/%s/%s' %(filename,b))
                arr = ds.ReadAsArray()

                # DO STUFF

                ds = None
```

Comment: You can mount the zip file. Many tools can do that. A lot Linux Distributions have that option preinstalled (e.g. Ubuntu). Tools for Linux: avfs, fuse-zip, gvfs, ... I know there are tools for Windows too, but I cannot name them.

Answer (score 5):

GDAL >= 2.1 is able to open the Sentinel-2 `.zip` file directly. For instance (from the [SENTINEL2 driver documentation page](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_sentinel2.html)):

```
$ gdalinfo S2A_OPER_PRD_MSIL1C_PDMC_20150818T101440_R022_V20150813T102406_20150813T102406.zip
```

Then you could convert subdataset into a `VRT` file (without extracting any `.jp2` file). This is an useful example from the driver documentation:

```
$ python -c "import sys; from osgeo import gdal; ds = gdal.Open(sys.argv[1]); open(sys.argv[2], 'wb').write(ds.GetMetadata('xml:VRT')[0].encode('utf-8'))" \
SENTINEL2_L1C:S2A_OPER_MTD_SAFL1C_PDMC_20150818T101440_R022_V20150813T102406_20150813T102406.xml:10m:EPSG_32632 10m.vrt
```

**Note:** The `.xml` metadata file can be read directly from the `.zip` file thanks to the [vsizip](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/UserDocs/ReadInZip) virtual file system: `/vsizip/S2XXXXX.zip/metadata.xml`

Comment: Yes, I mentioned that GDAL has the driver ... but I need to read the files with the GDAL module in python ... I don't want to do anything command line ... otherwhise I could as well extract the files through python and then read them ... but my plan would be to minimize the I/O by zipping directly into memory OR reading the entire dataset with the gdal module in Python if possible. Maybe theres a pythonic version of what you're suggesting, opening the dataset and then creating a vrt and reading it as array

Comment: I've just added further useful info extracted from the driver documentation. I think that it's a good starting point.

Comment: I successfully ran an example analogous to the one you posted above from the driver documentation. But this example expects the zipfile to be extracted entirely. You mentioned the `vsizip` system. This is also working fine for me through commandline (I can easily call `gdalinfo` et al.) but when I want to go through python, I can't really manage. I come as far as opening the `xml` metadata file to retrieve any kind of info, but I can't seem to actually access the imagery. If I use a `vsizip` path all the way to a `jp2` band, I'm receiving an error (while it's working through command line)

Comment: Something like `ds = gdal.open('/vsizip/path/to/S2XXXXX.zip/path/to/file')` should work. Is the above Python example working for you? IMHO the solution is there.

Comment: Ok, it does seem to be a **version** issue ... the gdal I was using with anaconda was 2.1.0 ... once I did the cumbersome upgrade to the conda-forge version 2.1.3, I could indeed read the bands separately out of the zipfile. In light of this, I will delete my previous comment